# Github API is not returning values for a user

Tags: angularjs, api, github

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o1fb31z6/3/

Okay, so I am doing a brief little project for an organization.

But here's the problem I get: whenever I query this user using the Search portion of the Github API, it returns nothing. I know the code works because if I adjust usernames, it returns values. Anyone ever have this problem?

My work around query above also gets them to return values, but some of the information is off (Fork Count).

app.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
    <title>Github API Webapp using AngularJS</title>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div data-ng-controller='GitHubCtrl' data-ng-init='getGitInfo()'>       
      <h1>Simple Github API Webapp</h1>
      <p>Search for a particular repo</p>
        <input type="text" ng-model="repoName" placeholder="Github repo name...">       
        <a href="#" ng-click="searchGitRepos()">Find Repos</a>
      <div ng-show='repoSearched'>
        <p><strong>Repos found by search:</strong></p>
        <ul ng-repeat='result in results'>
          <li><a href="{{result.html_url}}" target="_blank"> {{result.name}} </a></li>
          <li>User:{{result.owner.login}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>User: {{user.name}}
          <span class="smallname"><a href="{{user.html_url}}" target="_blank"> {{user.login}} </a></span>
        </h2>
      </div>        
      <div>
        <a href="{{ user.html_url }}" target="_blank">
        <img src="{{ user.avatar_url }}" width="80" height="80" alt="{{ user.login }}"></a>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="reposFound">
        <p><strong>Repos List:</strong></p>
        <ul ng-repeat="repo in repos">
          <li><a href="{{repo.html_url}}" target="_blank"> {{repo.name}} </a></li>
          <li>Forks Count: {{repo.forks_count}}</li>
          <li>Created at:{{repo.created_at}}</li>
          <li>Language: {{repo.language}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- End of controller div -->

    <script src='app.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('app',[]).controller('GitHubCtrl', GitHubCtrl);
function GitHubCtrl($scope, $http) {
  // Set the default user here
    $scope.username = 'aipub';
  // getGitInfo queries the Github api for user information and public repositories
    $scope.getGitInfo = function () {
      // This API call searches for logo of our user.
        $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.username).success(function (data) {
          $scope.user = data;
        });
      // This API call searches for the repos of the user
        $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/" + $scope.username + "/repos").success(function (data) {
          nameFormatter(data);
          $scope.repos = data;
          $scope.reposFound = data.length > 0;
        });
    }
  // comment about function below
    $scope.searchGitRepos = function () {
      $http.get("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=" + $scope.repoName + "+in:name+user:" + $scope.username).success(function (data) {
        $scope.results = data.items;
        $scope.repoSearched = data.items.length > 0;
      });
    }
}

// *args: array of objects of any length greater than 0. Capitalizes the name string of the each object
// in the array by splitting the words into their individual components, excluding if the words are 
// 'python' or 'mongo'.
  function nameFormatter(data) {
    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var formatName = data[i].name.split('-');
      for (var j=0; j < formatName.length; j++) {
        if (!(formatName[j] === 'python' || formatName[j] === 'mongo')) {
          formatName[j] = formatName[j].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + formatName[j].substr(1);
        }
      }
      data[i].name = formatName.join(' ');
    }
  }

// $http.get("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:tulun").success(function (data) {
//   console.log(data);
// });

// https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:tulun
// https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=user:aipub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the access token

you can try this project: https://github.com/JohnnyTheTank/angular-github-api-factory.

Comment: Do I? It seems to return the proper values for OTHER users. Do some users require authentication to view their info?

Comment: Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/o1fb31z6/

I put the JS in the html portion (sorry about that, made it work :) )

Comment: Sorry: https://jsfiddle.net/o1fb31z6/3/

If you change the $scope.username to something else, the search query should work... just doesn't for this particular organization.

Comment: this sample works for me. but which user should I test?

Comment: maybe it's just works for users and not for organisations

Comment: The user is aipub (the one stubbed into the file).

Comment: It shouldn't matter I don't think, according to the github docs.

https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#search-within-a-users-or-organizations-repositories

Comment: I searched for the user based on the factory link you just sent me -- has the same issues I have with this particular user. No idea what's going on with aipub.

Comment: you are right. you don't need an api key. I don't know whats this particular problem is